# Render Native Components in between HTML tags on a webview

Tags: android, html, webview, native

Can we embed our native Android components in between the normal HTML content and then render it on a webview?
For example, in a simple HTML page, if there is a button, I want to replace it with a Native Android Button.
How can we do that?

Comment: do you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with WebView (unless you split the HTML into multiple parts and render it in multiple WebViews with your button inserted inbetween, which may or may not work in your case).

Depending on the complexity of your HTML, you may want to consider this github project that renders HTML with native Android widgets: https://github.com/kobjects/htmlview

Comment: I'm trying to find this question answer related to hybrid apps. There I found that we can attach native components as siblings of WebView but not within the WebView.

Comment: but I'm not sure if there is not any Hybrid app which opens native component(say SomeCustomView) within webview? Do you have any idea?